# ¿Por qué no accede a mi segundo condicional?

Tags: javascript, php

Holaa,estoy intentando hacer que mi código ejecute una acción, pero no ejecuta el segundo condicional no sé por qué. No da ningún error ni nada por el estilo.

Código:

```
<?php

/*   Forma para pasar a backend.   */

$usually_get = '<script type="text/javascript">
  const fpPromise = import("https://openfpcdn.io/fingerprintjs/v3")
    .then(FingerprintJS => FingerprintJS.load())

  fpPromise
    .then(fp => fp.get())
    .then(result => {
   const visitorId = result.visitorId;
    //   console.log(visitorId);
const furious = localStorage.getItem("us"); //Value null en el primer acceso.

        if (furious === null) {
            console.log("first access detected");
            localStorage.setItem("us", visitorId);

        }
        else{
            console.log("nvm");
        }
        
        if (furious > 0) {
                console.log("it was successfully put");
            }

    });
     

</script>';
echo $usually_get;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/*   Forma para pasar a backend.   */

$usually_get = '<script type="text/javascript">
(async function () {
   const fpPromise = await import("https://openfpcdn.io/fingerprintjs/v3").then(
   (FingerprintJS) => FingerprintJS.load()
   );
   const result = await fpPromise.get();
   
      const visitorId = await result.visitorId;
      const furious = await localStorage.getItem("us"); //Value null en el primer acceso.

      if (furious === null) {
         console.log("first access detected");
         localStorage.setItem("us", visitorId);
      } else if(furious.length > 0) {
         console.log("it was successfully put");
      } else {
         console.log("nvm");
      }

   
})();
     

</script>';
echo $usually_get;

?>
```

o tal vez solo esto:

```
if (furious.length > 0) {
    console.log("it was successfully put");
}
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu aporte.